# Why I cannot access to this instance variable (in model) from another method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method in my model and I call it with `before_create`:

```
  def first_position
    if [...]
      [...]
    else
      @last_known = Picture.where(user_id: user_id).order('position desc').first
      self.position = nil
    end
  end
```

And I have another method that I call with `after_commit`:

```
  def default_position
    pictures = Picture.where(user_id: user_id).where('created_at > ?', @last_known.created_at)

    i = @last_known.position + 1
    pictures.each do |pic|
      pic.position = i
      i += 1
    end
  end
```

But in `default_position`, `@last_known` returns **nil**. Do you know why?

**EDIT:**

Well, I discovered that I have two commit, but the one that concerns the picture is second, so `@last_known` is set at the first commit but disappears at the second commit.

Comment: "Do you know why?" - yes. Because it's not initialized or initialized to nil. But it's impossible to tell why, without a [mcve].

Comment: Because instance variables can't be shared across methods. So `@last_known` which is defined in `first_position` can't be available in `default_position`

Comment: @pavan what are you talking about? Are you thinking of some other type of variables?

Comment: please try a simpler approach just to make sure of the problem, because I see a branch there, try putting "binding.pry" or byebug or any breakpoint in `first_position` after the `else` line, make sure this block gets executed in the first place.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Auh.. I mean `@last_known` variable won't be available to `default_position` method because its not defined. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Pavan: yes, you are. If you're not confusing this with local variables, I don't know how you got your ruby/rails badges :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm not wrong. I've checked myself running a sample code. How an instance variable which is defined in one method will be available to another method? :)

Comment: @Pavan: I'd like to see code of that test :) "How an instance variable ... will be available in another method" - that's what they __do__.

Comment: @Pavan copy-paste this in your IRB console to see it working: `class A ; def set ; @some_var = 12 ; end ; def get ; @some_var ; end ; end ; a = A.new ; a.set ; a.get` (`set` method assign a value to the instance variable `@some_var`, method `get` returns the value for that instance variable). If `get` is called _before_ `set`, then you will end up with `nil` instead of `12`

Comment: Alright, Alright I need a break :)

Comment: don't know if this could be the problem but rails 4 cancels further processing if a filter returns false... https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Canceling+callbacks
that seems to be possible in your first_position-method

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. If I break after the else condition in `first_position`, I can see the value of `@last_known`, so it's initialized, that's why I don't understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

Initially I thought that ActiveRecord reloads the record sometime before the after_commit, or at least reinitializes it. I've checked with Rails 5.2.1 and nothing happens with instance variables, they remain correctly set. This means that (unless you're using older Rails), there simply are no pictures for the given user and your code does not seem to handle that.

Also, your `after_commit` will run after you update the object as well, which might be the issue as your variable will not be set in that case.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, thanks for your answer. If I break after the else condition in `first_position`, I can see the vlue of `@last_known`, that's why I don't understand my problem :/

Comment: @escanxr is it possible your `after_commit` is not failing after creating, but perhaps after updating an object? Without the full stacktrace it is difficult to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Yes @Marcin it was the problem, so I used another method for doing what I wanted. Sorry for the lack of precision, there is so much code that if I had to put everything it would be huge and unclear.. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ah, okay. Usually it helps to paste the stacktrace, somebody would've caught that you're updating the records somewhere :)

Comment: Yep, sorry, I will give more informations and explain better next time!